How to differentiate address sanitizer error from script error?
When using Address Sanitizer when either of ASAN or the actual program fails, the exitcode is always 1. How can I differentiate one from the other? I tried setting exitcode option in ASAN_OPTIONS to something other than 1, but still ASAN is exiting with 1. What can I do?
Here is the sample code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char *s = malloc(5);
    strcpy(s, "Hello world!");
    printf("string is: %s\n", s);
    //free(s);
    return 0;
}

Here is the command used to compile:
gcc -g -fsanitize=address -o /tmp/tmp.bin /tmp/tmp.c
Here is the command used to execute:
ASAN_OPTIONS=exitcode=0 /tmp/tmp.bin ; echo $?
Here whatever exitcode I used (other than 0), I'm getting 1 as output of echo $?

Do you get ASAN errors without the script?  If so, fix them now so you don't have to worry about the exit code.

@StephenNewell what you are suggesting is a workaround. I'm expecting an actual solution to this issue

By "script" you are referring to a compiled c program, I presume?

@EugeneSh. Yes.

I tried setting exitcode option in ASAN_OPTIONS to something other than 1, but still ASAN is exiting with 1. - so maybe it's because your program is exiting with 1?

ASAN is exiting with 1 regardless of program exit code. What I'm searching for is something like error-exitcode option in Valgrind, if Valgrind fails it exits with given exitcode, otherwise forwards programs exitcode.

How about you show us your invocation command along with the test code, similarly to the almost duplicate question?

@EugeneSh. Already checked that question. For that question, solution would be using exitcode=0. But if I do that, then I wouldn't know if any ASAN error occurs or not.

Works for me with the code from that question. Note, that ASAN_OPTIONS are needed for the invocation of the compiled program, not for compiling it. That is, you need to invoke it like this > ASAN_OPTIONS="exitcode=123" ./leak ; echo $?

With your invocation string I get 0. Perhaps your gcc is very old or something?

@EugeneSh. Yes, gcc is very very old (gcc5.4). But mainly, in the example I added in the question, it is working as expected, returning with exitcode I provided in options. But in the actual case, it is always returning 1. Not sure.

@SouravKannanthaB Well, I'd suggest updating gcc, I suppose older versions might not be implementing this option correctly. Or your actual code is not working exactly how you believe it is working.

@EugeneSh., well at the moment I'm unable to update gcc. But just to confirm, you are saying that if I give exitcode=x and any ASAN error occurs, it exits with code x? Not always 1 as I'm facing here?

@SouravKannanthaB Well, I certainly didn't do any extensive testing, but with the code you posted and invocation with exitcode=123, it returns 123 for me. Using gcc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0

@EugeneSh. Yes, found it, ASAN error is happening in a child process and it is exiting as expected. Parent process is then catching it and exiting with 1. Thanks for your help.

To differentiate between an AddressSanitizer (ASan) error and a program exit, set ASAN_OPTIONS=halt_on_error=0 to allow the program to continue running after an ASan error. Then check the logs or output for ASan-specific error messages rather than relying solely on the exit code. Unfortunately, exitcode in ASAN_OPTIONS doesn't work as expected in all cases due to tool limitations. A more robust approach is to wrap your program in a script that captures ASan output for analysis.

Unfortunately, exitcode in ASAN_OPTIONS doesn't work as expected in all cases due to tool limitations - do you have a reference?

Although there is no official and direct statement highlighting this particular limitation. but The LLVM AddressSanitizer Documentation explains the usage of ASAN_OPTIONS but doesn't clarify the limitations in detail.

@0x23 The page you linked to doesn't even mention the Asan option exitcode so where did you get "doesn't work as expected in all cases due to tool limitations" from? It works just fine for me.
